# How to mount a partition at startup in Linux Mint 17.2 KDE by using a GUI?

Tags: linux-mint, partition, kde, gui, automounting

I would like to have a GUI to set one of my NTFS drives to be automatically mounted at startup as it contains data synchronized with apps that also run at startup (Dropbox, Megasync etc) which otherwise give error.

In the past there was a "Drives" applications mentioned in some solutions that I cannot find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution for KDE (but not obvious enough given that I have posted the question and also the initial part of this answer on `gnome-disk-utility`) is Removable Devices tool:

[image]

---

A simple solution is to install `gnome-disk-utility` in Synaptic Manager.

Then, starting 'Disks' follow [this](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/07/mount-partitions-automatically-ubuntu-14-04/) procedure. Also [here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1197), even with a video example [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8496583/Random/MountTuto.mp4).

[image]

As I already had a label for that partition ("DEPO") and links in different applications to the default mount point `media/cip/DEPO`, I used the same path for Mount Point.

[image]

Comment: Thx for stating the obvious! I was looking for a native KDE GUI tool but everywhere I looked everyone suggested editing fstab …ugh! And the solution was just laying in front of me :D

Comment: @WooYek - In fact the obvious solution for KDE (but not obvious enough given that I have posted the question and also the initial part of this answer on gnome-disk-utility) is Removable Devices tool: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Click "System Settings," then "removable disks." Then click the box next to your data partition.

Comment: Notice that the OP asks "I would like to have a GUI"; which GUI is your answer specific to? Please update your post to say so, then flag this comment as "no longer necessary". Thank you!